# (Flask) How to make an If statement in html that detects the last item in a for loop

Tags: python, html, flask, frontend, flask-sqlalchemy

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        {% for post in posts %}
          <div class="post-preview">
            <a href="{{ url_for('post', post_id=post.id) }}">
              <h2 class="post-title">
                {{ post.title }}
              </h2>
              <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                {{ post.subtitle }}
              </h3>
            </a>
            <p class="post-meta">Posted by {{ post.author }} on {{ post.date_posted.strftime('%B %d, %Y') }}</p>
          </div>

            {% if post == posts[-1]  %}
              <br />
            {% else %}
              <hr />
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

Im making a web application on flask and this is the snippet of my code to the articles template I have a sqlite database that contains the articles, how can I make an if statement that detects if the post is the last in the loop since im making an hr per article but not on the last one
`{% if post == posts[-1]  %}` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Except I'm not understanding your question, you don't need to check if you've gotten to the last in the loop to add hr tag, why not just use the hr tag after the loop?

Comment: there are multiple posts, I would like to display hr per posts but not on the last one

Comment: You could always do `for i,post in enumerate(posts)` and then do the `<hr>` at the BEGINNING of the loop if i != 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Default Flask uses jinja2 as default Template Engine[[1]](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#templates) and that's what you're using. Jinja2 provides `loop.last` variable[[2]](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures) that you can use as follows:

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        {% for post in posts %}
          <div class="post-preview">
            <a href="{{ url_for('post', post_id=post.id) }}">
              <h2 class="post-title">
                {{ post.title }}
              </h2>
              <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                {{ post.subtitle }}
              </h3>
            </a>
            <p class="post-meta">Posted by {{ post.author }} on {{ post.date_posted.strftime('%B %d, %Y') }}</p>
          </div>

            {% if loop.last  %}
              <br />
            {% else %}
              <hr />
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```